# Rapid acceleration and deceleration of Space X's BFR

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, estimation, space-travel

Given that momentum is the product of speed and weight (Velocity x Weight) would rapid deceleration or acceleration in weighless space, of Space X's BFR have an impact on its passengers. I ask because if it is to travel at 27000km/h most of its journey would be spent accelerating and decelerating very much limited by earthlike g forces as airliners do, therfore minimizing on the reduction of travel time. Would most of the braking and accelerating have to take place in space at zero gravity?

Answer (score 2):

> if it is to travel at 27000km/h most of its journey would be spent
>   accelerating and decelerating

There are 2 things wrong with that.

First, and least important, 27,000 km/h is equal to 7.5 km/s, which is the speed required to stay in low orbit around the earth. In order to leave orbit and travel to the moon or even Mars, as the BFR is intended to do, the speed needs to be higher than that. The Apollo spacecraft travelled up to about 10 km/s or 36,000 km/h on their trip to the moon. To get to Mars and keep the duration of the trip reasonable, you'd want something more like 13 km/s (46,800 km/h).

Far more important than the actual speed though, is the acceleration. When a rocket takes off, it accelerates at rates that the human body can tolerate. It starts slowly but, as the fuel is used up and the rocket gets lighter, acceleration increases up to a maximum of about 4g. That is quite survivable. And, it does not need to be tolerated for a long time. At 4g, your speeds increases by about 40m/s **every second**. If that was sustained, you'd achieve 7.5 km/s after just 3 minutes. Apollo only achieved 4g briefly, and took about about 11 minutes to reach orbit. After that, the astronauts were just coasting with no more acceleration - until the blast to put them on the path to the moon at 10 km/s. [This link](http://www.murdoconline.net/archives/870.html) shows how acceleration changed during Apollo take-offs.

Remember though that, once you are in orbit, you can take things easy. You no longer have to get away as fast as possible, to avoid burning all your fuel near the ground. Hence, you can achieve the extra speed by using much lower acceleration, for longer. The worst part by far is take-off - and landing, when the same thing happens more or less in reverse: you get a lot of acceleration in a short time to slow you down to landing speed. In between, you coast without any acceleration, floating at 0g.

> Would most of the braking and accelerating have to take place in space
>   at zero gravity?

As Einstein pointed out in his theory of General Relativity, there is no way you can distinguish gravity from acceleration. As far as the astronauts are concerned, acceleration feels exactly like gravity. If they were to accelerate at 1g, it would feel precisely the same as if they were standing on earth. So they will only feel "gravity" while accelerating - or , of course, while standing on a planet.

Answer (score 1):

From memory, the theoretical maximum acceleration of the famous Concorde plane was about 0.9g whereas commercially it was doing 1/3 g. Part of the difference was passenger comfort. Subsonic passenger planes  are below 2 m/s^2. Such an acceleration is far below that of the space shuttle, up to 3g, which is again limited by human resistance anyway. Therefore, using a rocket for human transportation is quite silly. First the Hyperloop and then that...

Answer (score 0):

Momentum is velocity times **mass** not weight. In space you might be weightless but you are not massless, therefore you still requires a force to accelerate.

The g-force on you is the vector sum of your accelerations. Vector sum means that the relative directions of the accelerations which are being added affects their sum.  Being in a gravitational field is equivalent to accelerating in the opposite direction. If you are accelerating vertically at rate $a$ against a gravitational field of strength $g$ then you experience a g-force of $a+g$. Accelerating at the same rate $a$ in empty space where $g\approx 0$ the g-force on you is $a$.

So yes, to keep the g-force on you close to $1g_0$ (the value when you are stationary at the surface of the Earth) you would have to accelerate slowly ($a\approx 0$) close to Earth, and gradually increase your acceleration as the gravitational field strength diminished while your distance from the Earth's surface increased. In empty space, far from the Earth and other planets, you could increase your acceleration to $a\approx g_0$. Most of the acceleration and braking would be done in empty space.